# how to share an object between multiple jsp pages in liferay?

Tags: jsp, liferay

I'm developing a liferay portlet. In this portlet I fetch the user information from database in portlet class and save them in a resultset. How can I share this resultset between portlet class and jsp pages?

Answer (score 0):

Save the user objects in an arraylist and use session to save this arraylist.
You can make it available throughout the portlet.
[Setting and getting is explained in this.](http://longgoldenears.blogspot.com/2008/03/liferay-session-sharing-demystified.html)

[Example](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/10954894)

Comment: I have some problem using session. In view.jsp I get username and password and pass them to portlet class. Then I fetch user info from database and save them in session and go to patientInfo.jsp using "actionResponse.setRenderParameter("jspPage","/patientInfo.jsp")"

Comment: How are you setting the value in session ? Try the example present in the link I had shared. It will surely work that way.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to hold the session thin, in this case I would put the data in the request.

java:

```
public class MyTestPortlet extends MVCPortlet {
    @Override
    public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
        User user = getCurrentUser(renderRequest);
        renderRequest.setAttribute("UserName", user.getScreenName());
        super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
    }
...
}
```

jsp:

```
Hello ${UserName}!!!
```